# Finding pairs of integers such that $9x^2+y$ and $9y^2+x$ are both perfect squares

Tags: number-theory

> Find all pairs of positive integers $(x, y)$ such that $9x^2+y$ and $9y^2+x$ are both perfect squares.

My process:

Supposed, $9x^2+y=a^2$ and $9y^2+x=b^2$

Then,
$8(x+y)(x-y)=(a+b)(a-b)$

I don't know how to continue further. Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: Check your algebra. $9(x+y)(x-y)-(x-y)=(9(x+y)-1)(x-y)$

Comment: $$(9x^2+y)-(9y^2+x)=9(x^2-y^2)-(x-y)=(x-y)(9x+9y-1).$$

Comment: Note that you must have $9y^2+x \geq (3y+1)^2$, ie $x > 6y > y$, and similarly $y > x$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such pair.

$9x^2+y$ a perfect square; $y$ positive; implies $9x^2+y \ge (3x+1)^2$ which implies $y \geq 6x+1$ which implies (for $x$ nonegative) that $y>x$. Likewise we derive $x > y$. No pair $(x,y)$ of numbers satisfy both simultaneously.